# In meterial 3, the background color of the BottomAppBar does not change. Pink shades appear in the background of the BottomAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, material3

I Upgrade  flutter 3.3.10 to 3.7.3.In material 3, the background colour of the BottomAppBar  does not change.Pink shades appear in the background of the BottomAppBar,BottomStyleSheet etc .and BottomAppBar and BottomNavigationBar do not merge, they act separately
[`see image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62q0M.png).
It works fine when I switch to the material 2 design, but some animations would benefit from the material 3 design instead.

```
import 'package:bottom_navbar/constants/app_assets.dart';
import 'package:bottom_navbar/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:bottom_navbar/constants/app_labels.dart';
import 'package:bottom_navbar/constants/app_styles.dart';
import 'package:bottom_navbar/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int ci = 0;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: AppLabels.addOrEditHero,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: AppColors.colorWhite,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(width: 3, color: AppColors.colorWhite)),
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.add,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          )),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 8,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 8 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier!,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            selectedFontSize: 1.4 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier!,
            selectedItemColor: AppColors.primary,
            selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.primary),
            currentIndex: ci,
            unselectedLabelStyle: AppStyles.bottomNavButtonStyle,
            selectedLabelStyle: AppStyles.bottomNavButtonStyle,
            unselectedItemColor: AppColors.menuButton,
            onTap: (i) {
              setState(() {
                ci = i;
              });
            },
            showUnselectedLabels: false,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity), label: 'Activity'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), label: 'Notifications'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag), label: 'Cart'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Main Screen')),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: set elevation of `BottomAppBar` to 0

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: can provide data instead of variable while `AppStyles` is unknown here

Answer (score 5):

This is happened when you use material3 with elevated widget because of surfaceTintColor parameter , you can fix this be change it to color you want, if you want to hide color just make elevation =0

```
    surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
    
    elevation: 0,
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know why this happening, but you can fix this issue by setting canvas color in `MaterialApp`'s `ThemeData` like this,

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        canvasColor: Colors.white,///here
      ),
),
```

There must be some issue with `colorScheme` in `ThemeData`
You can also use this,

```
ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        // canvasColor: Colors.white,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.highContrastLight(),
      ),
```

Comment: thanks! 
disable the material3 i think is good way as the layout changed so much since new flutter update

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the BottomAppBar with the Theme widget and add `useMaterial3: false` for ThemeData

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(useMaterial3: false),
  child: BottomAppBar(
    shape: widget.notchedShape,
    color: Colors.green,
    notchMargin: widget.floatingMargin,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: items,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "**padding 0**" and then **wrap child with container** with custom  color

like this:

```
BottomAppBar(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  height: 60,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.yellow,
    child: Row(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This normally occurs when you have set `material3` to `true` in your ThemeData. The simplest solution is to set `elevation` in your BottomAppBar to `0.0`. For instance:

```
bottomNavigationBar: const BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.white,
    elevation: TAppSize.s0,
    height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
  ),
```

Hope this helps!